# Android File Uploading to Server Empty

Tags: android, xml, stored-procedures, file-upload, ftp

Hi I have a xml file on my phone's disk. And I wanna upload it to server. I achieved it but the problem is xml file is empty when it is in server. The function below is running correctly , I mean the xml file is uploading to server correctly but it's empty. Why?

```
 private void uploadXmlFile(int levelID){


        String FTP_HOST= "181.50.149.1";
        String FTP_USER = "kdirrrri";
        String FTP_PASS  ="123456";

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/kadirgame/"+levelID+".xml");


        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

       try {

           client.connect(FTP_HOST,21);
           client.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);
           client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
           client.changeDirectory("/levels/");

        //  client.upload(f);
           client.upload(f, new MyTransferListener());

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           try {
               client.disconnect(true);    
           } catch (Exception e2) {
               e2.printStackTrace();
           }
       }




   }
```

Comment: Most likely the path of the file is wrong.. please verify that your file is in the folder given by.. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/kadirgame/"`

Comment: I don't tihnk so. Because I have delete() fuction which is delete file on sdcard. So this delete accesses  the file by this:   
           File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/kadirgame/"+levelID+".xml");

they are the same.So this line can access the file.

Comment: this doesn't mean anything.. you could delete a file.. just like you upload it.. empty.. can you go and check if the correct file with some data inside exists at that location..

Comment: I checked and there is one and not empty